# Swift Status bar height change

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar, whatsapp, hotspot

Using Xcode 8 and Swift 2.3.

In my app when I get WhatsApp call or enable hotspot,
Status bar height changes and alignment gets altered.

How do I refresh the screen when status bar height changes,
So screen gets adjusted.

I came across these two delegate methods but no idea how to use this for my requirement.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didChangeStatusBarFrame oldStatusBarFrame: CGRect)
{
    print("Frame Change old")
}

func application(application: UIApplication, willChangeStatusBarFrame newStatusBarFrame: CGRect)
{
    print("Frame Change new")


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those delegates must be added to the AppDelegate.swift, if I'm not mistaken.

Then you need to resize the Window putting this code inside the new status bar delegate

```
if let window = self.window {
    window.clipsToBounds = true
    window.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: newStatusBarFrame.size.height, width: window.frame.size.width, height: window.frame.size.height);
    window.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: window.frame.size.width, height: window.frame.size.height);
}
```

Haven't tested the code so I hope it works